# Unable to find and add an ASP.NET 5 Class Library project to a solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, projects-and-solutions, class-library

I recently created a new ASP.NET 5 Web App and a standard C# Class Library only to find out that the ASP.NET 5 Web App can't reference. I did research and saw that there is an ASP.NET 5 Class Library but can't find it anywhere in my fully updated VS2015 Enterprise.

Is it called Class Library (Package) or Class Library (Portable)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Class Library (Package). In fact, you can just add a project.json file with the minimum content and <strike>reference that</strike> add it to your solution by right clicking on your solution and selecting *Add* > *Existing project...*.

[image]

VS will create xproj file as soon as you reference it (which is only needed for VS). Then, you can reference it like below:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "3-class-lib": ""
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": {},
        "dnxcore50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-23516"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, the `3-class-lib` is the name of the class library folder which ends up being the name. You can refer to [this](https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/codemash-samples/tree/6eb571f4e59c29ee33a3794d232eb6099acf4670/4-class-lib-ref) for this sample.

Comment: Perfect! Do you know if the Unit Test Project template will work with ASP.NET 5 or are you supposed to create it a different way?

Comment: it's different. Follow this: https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dnx.html

Comment: Do you know why when adding a Class Library (Package) it is initially referencing net451 and dotnet5.4 which has dependencies like Microsoft.CSharp, System.Linq, etc.. Should I be replacing these with the 2 frameworks to match my asp.net 5 webapp: dnxcore50 and dnx451? Or should I be using all 4 in the class libraries? It seems like once I replace them all of my references to System are dead.